# NO NETBEANS PROJECTS ADDED Error

Tags: java, github, netbeans, zip, netbeans-plugins

I am trying to import a projetc (in ZIP file) in my netbeans8.2. It is downloaded from GitHub (link: https://github.com/wdalmut/vanet). While importing the project from Zip it shows the error and no project becomes imported.  Why this happening and how can I run a complete project into netbeans 8.2 ?

Comment: Try this: 
1.Choose File > New Project (Ctrl-Shift-N on Windows/Cmd-Shift-N on OS X).
2.Choose Java > Java Project with Existing Sources.

For further details, look at https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/project-setup.html?print=yes#projects-importing

Answer (score 0):

The import from zip option in netbeans doesn't support importing anything, its only meant to import other netbeans projects that have been packed as a zip file. If you want to import existing code into netbeans you will need to do so manually. For help doing this you can refer to [this article](https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/project-setup.html?print=yes#projects-importing) on the netbeans site.